# Strange behavior while trying to get the most recent LogStream from CloudWatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get the most recent LogStream for a LogGroup from AWS CloudWatch using boto3 in python.

This is my code -

```
import boto3
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='saml')
client = session.client(service_name = 'logs' ,region_name='ap-southeast-2')
t1 = datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow())
response = client.filter_log_events(logGroupName='/aws/lambdagroup/name', limit = 1, startTime = int(t1))
```

I get the following output

```
{'events': [], 'searchedLogStreams': [{'logStreamName': '2019/04/28/[$LATEST]09e21ad3881e456b9cdc5cd48ff3d919', 'searchedCompletely': True}, {'logStreamName': '2019/04/28/[$LATEST]29919c675dd546eea103789f0b5943
79', 'searchedCompletely': True}, {'logStreamName': '2019/04/28/[$LATEST]679942908fba4d7287cc5ac288373568', 'searchedCompletely': True}, {'logStreamName': '2019/04/28/[$LATEST]68874fb83e8b47dfb0efc410b9314528',
 'searchedCompletely': True}, {'logStreamName': '2019/04/28/[$LATEST]6c9e152d09574c49a37da86769e2a9b3........................ etc
```

Question - Why am I getting logs from 04/28 onwards when my start time is specified to be from current time?

I just want to get the most recent LogStream from a specific LogGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you misunderstand `LogStream`, and `LogEvent`.

Here's the api of [`filter_log_events`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.filter_log_events):

```
response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName='string',
    logStreamNames=[
        'string',
    ],
    logStreamNamePrefix='string',
    startTime=123,
    endTime=123,
    filterPattern='string',
    nextToken='string',
    limit=123,
    interleaved=True|False
)
```

If you don't specify the `logStreamNames`, it will search events in **all LogStreams**.

That's why you got `'events': []` and `'searchedLogStreams': [{'logStreamName':...`

To get the latest LogStream, you could use [`describe_log_streams`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams):

```
response = client.describe_log_streams(
    logGroupName='/aws/group/name',
    orderBy='LastEventTime',
    descending=True,
    limit=1
)
```